# In Gradle Kotlin, how to iterate like each{} in Groovy?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, groovy

In the Android doc, there's a build.gradle snippet describing the set up for `com.google.protobuf`:

```
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc"
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java {
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However it is Groovy syntax, which doesn't work for Kotlin. The IDE highlights `each` saying something like "unresolved reference".

So what's the alternative for `each {}` in Kotlin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
all().configureEach { task ->
...
```

(from [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin))

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem?

Comment: Yes it solves, thanks, the error reported by IDE regarding "each" is gone, though more errors appear. Those are irrelevant to this question though.